# python psycopg2 internal error on string formatter

Tags: python, psycopg2

Hi I'm trying the following script

```
import psycopg2 as pq
import os

# Create the database
os.system('dropdb ptest')
os.system('createdb ptest')
# connect to the database
cn = pq.connect('dbname=ptest user=myname')
cr = cn.cursor()

# the wierd tuple at the EOL below is to preserve the list 
# lookup in case that is where the error is.
cr.execute('CREATE TABLE id1 (%s varchar, %s int PRIMARY KEY, %s int, %s int, %s varchar)' % tuple(['fund', 'sleeve_id', 'sub_id', 'level_id', 'Entity_id'])
cr.execute('INSERT INTO id1 (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s) VALUES ("%s","%s","%s","%s","%s");' % tuple(['fund', 'sleeve_id', 'sub_id', 'level_id', 'Entity_id']+['RHUBARB RHUBARB - RHUBARB RHUBARB', '2', '1', '1', 'CRUMB1']))
```

and I get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
psycopg2.InternalError: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
```

What am I doing wrong?

btw the same error occurs with the line

```
cr.execute('INSERT INTO id1 (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s) VALUES ("%s","%s","%s","%s","%s");' % ('fund', 'sleeve_id', 'sub_id', 'level_id', 'Entity_id','RHUBARB RHUBARB - RHUBARB RHUBARB', '2', '1', '1', 'CRUMB1'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay for completeness the tricky bit was feeding the field names in as string formatters too.

I split the code into two sections.

```
import psycopg2 as pq
import os

# Create the database
os.system('dropdb ptest')
os.system('createdb ptest')
# connect to the database
cn = pq.connect('dbname=ptest user=myname')
cr = cn.cursor()

# the wierd tuple at the EOL below is to preserve the list 
# lookup in case that is where the error is.
cr.execute('CREATE TABLE id1 (%s varchar, %s int PRIMARY KEY, %s int, %s int, %s varchar)' % tuple(['fund', 'sleeve_id', 'sub_id', 'level_id', 'Entity_id'])
SQL = 'INSERT INTO id1 (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s) VALUES' % tuple(['fund', 'sleeve_id', 'sub_id', 'level_id', 'Entity_id'])
SQL = SQL + ' (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s);'
data = tuple(['RHUBARB RHUBARB - RHUBARB RHUBARB', '2', '1', '1', 'CRUMB1'])
cr.execute(SQL,data)
```

and that worked fine and (I believe) remains safe from SQL injection type attacks.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to commit the first statement that creates the table, before you can run any inserts on it. Try running `cn.commit()` in between your two SQL statements to see if that resolves the issue.

Alternatively, set `autocommit=True` when you create your initial connection to the database.

Comment: Thanks @Talvalin this wound up being a little simpler. The second set of `"%s"` were the wrong kind of quotation for pyscopg2. postgres is looking for single quotes it transpires. Replacing them with `%r` or changing `cr.execute(SQL % data)` with `cr.execute(SQL,data)` did the trick.